# How can we program the keys of a keyboard for a specific python program?

Tags: python, function, input, keyboard, keyboard-events

I want to write a python program which has 3 functions f1,f2 and f3,and there is also a 4th function g.The use of function g is to program three keys from the keyboard,say "a","s","d" such that when I run the program,and press say "a",it calls function f1,when "s" is pressed f2 is called,and when "d" is pressed f3 is called,i.e.,I want to reassign the work of a,s,d to call the functions f1,f2,f3 respectively.

The restrictions are that--

1.When I stop pressing say "a",and start pressing "b",I want the program to terminate the job f1 was doing(not the whole program,only f1's job) and start working on f2's commands.

2.If both "a" and "s" are pressed simultaneously,the later of the two being pressed will be executed only,work of the former will be terminated.

3.If after pressing and holding say "a" and then releasing "a",nothing is 
pressed,then the function f1 should be terminated within 0.0001 seconds,i.e.,Allowable time lag to switch from f1 to f2(or nothing) after "s" is pressed=less than 0.0001 seconds.

NOTE---I am also not looking for a virtual/secondary onscreen keyboard but modify my original one,and only a few keys,only for this program.

ReSearch effort---Searching on google,and other sites gave me answers related to keyboard automation,pyautogui.etc.which is similar but not exactly what I want here,and I have no idea how to start this problem,So no code is given.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=python+keyboard+event&ia=web

Comment: tldr; please format your question well.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Keyboard module.
On cmd:

`pip3 install keyboard`

And code :

```py
import keyboard 
def f1():
    #whatever
def f2():
    #whatever
def f3():
    #whatever
while True: 
    try:  
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):  
            f1()

        if keyboard.is_pressed('b'):  
            f2()

        if keyboard.is_pressed('c'):  
            f3()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        continue
```

Comment: As soon as I type any key,the program is ending,and not continuing indefinitely(as it should be due to the while loop).Why?

Comment: @ManasDogra what have you defined in the functions?

Comment: f1 returns 1 f2 returns 2,f3 returns 3-no arguments in f.

Comment: Try using `print` instead of `return`, i.e `print(1)` instead of `return 1`

Comment: prints the same result too many times,and does not respond for 2ndary inputs

Comment: And after that program closes like before

Comment: There is  no error message as there is error handling. Check out the edit by @Nobody

Comment: Nothing changed.Many same results are printed,no second output is being accepted as program closes suddenly.